# How can I send message within express module's get method?

Tags: express, get, emit

I'm trying to create a game chat room with the following code:

```
    var namespace = io.of('/game');

    namespace.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("connect~~?");
        socket.on('join_room', function(data){
            console.log("QEWEQWE");
        });
    });

    app.get('/game/[a-zA-Z0-9]+', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/game.html');
        console.log("join room");
        res.app.emit('join_room', {}); // not working.
        req.sockets.emit('join_room', {}); // not working.
        namespace.emit('join_room', {}); // not working.

    }
```

I know that is how to send message with client to server. But, I am wondering how to emit "socket.on". from "get method"

Comment: No need to say 'thankyou' at the end of a question